# Is there a specific way to conditionally create an average from within a column in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Sample data:

```
Lang|Book_Type|Numbers|Weight
--------------------------------
A   |  B1     |  20   | 5 
------------------------
B   |  B1     |  20   | 4
------------------------
C   |  B1     |  30   | 3
------------------------
A   |  B2     |  40   | 5
------------------------
B   |  B2     |  20   | 4
------------------------
C   |  B2     |  50   | 10
------------------------
A   |  B3     |  20   | 2
------------------------
B   |  B3     |  20   | 5
------------------------
C   |  B3     |  50   | 10
```

So, basically what is the problem statement here is that I want another column/measure to have an average numbers% per Book Type, such that:

> B1: A: 20/(20+20+30)=28.5%    B:28.5%     C: 42.8%
> B2: A: 40/(40+20+50)=36.36%    B:18.18%     C: 45.45%
> B2: A: 20/(20+20+50)=22.22%    B:22.22%     C: 55.56%
>
> A: average(28.5%*5,36.36%*5,55.56%*2) or 463.92/(5+5+2) or 38.66

Similarly, for B & C.

I tried using Weighted average per category, but the numbers seemed to be not perfectly accurate. Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Used as dataset (NewTable):

```
TAVG = 
DATATABLE(
    "Lang", STRING,
    "Book_Type", STRING,
    "value", INTEGER,
    "Weight", INTEGER,
    {
{"A","B1","20","5" }, 
{"B","B1","20","4" },
{"C","B1","30","3" },
{"A","B2","40","5" },
{"B","B2","20","4" },
{"C","B2","50","10"},
{"A","B3","20","2" },
{"B","B3","20","5" },
{"C","B3","50","10"}

    }
)
```

Simple AVG:

```
Average% =
DIVIDE (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( TAVG[value] ),
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( TAVG[value] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( TAVG ), TAVG[Book_Type] = SELECTEDVALUE ( TAVG[Book_Type] ) )
    )
)
```

Then you can write another measure for eg:

```
W_avg = SUMX(TAVG, TAVG[Weight] * TAVG[Average%])
```

[image]

Comment: hello. It returns blank column in average % column.

Comment: I use your sample data to achieve the above result. Do you create MEASURE or CALCULATE Column? (I use MEASURE) Are you correctly refer to your table/columns?

Comment: i used average % as calc column

Comment: i used average % as measure & then added W_avg. but it seems W_avg returns the sum of all rather than average

Comment: Right, in my answer i have use SUMX instead of AVERAGEX; Please replace this and try again.

Comment: sorry, it returns avg of all values  ignoring book type

Comment: Add calculate with filter to get group context:

W_avg  = calculate(AVERAGEX(TAVG, TAVG[Weight] * TAVG[Average%]) , FILTER ( ALL ( TAVG[Book_Type]), TAVG[Book_Type] = SELECTEDVALUE ( TAVG[Book_Type] ) )

Comment: It is giving the same result. Average of all entries rather than per bank.